# Perl : Cannot open a file with filename passed as argument

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, filenames

I am passing two filenames from a DOS batch file to a Perl script.

```
my $InputFileName = $ARGV[0];
my $OutputFileName = $ARGV[1];
```

Only the input file physically exists while the Outputfile must be created by the script.

```
open HANDLE, $OutputFileName or die $!;
open (HANDLE, ">$OutputFileName);
open HANDLE, ">$OutputFileName" or die $!;
```

All three fail.

However the following works fine.

```
open HANDLE, ">FileName.Txt" or die $!;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Edit : Error message is : No such file or directory at Batchfile.pl at line nn

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` may help you to see what the error is. By the way, what's that "Die" function?

Comment: What error message are you getting from the call to `die()`. Without that information we're pretty much guessing at what the problem might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way is to use the three-parameter form of `open` (with the mode as a separate parameter) with lexical file handles. Also `die` doesn't have a capital `D`.

Like this

```
open my $out, '>', $OutputFileName or die $!;
```

but your last example should work assuming you have spelled `die` properly in your actual code.

If you are providing a path to the filename that doesn't exist then you also need to create the intermediate directories.

The die string will tell you the exact problem. What message do you get when this fails?

Comment: I highly recommend also `use autodie` at the top of your file (after you type `use strict` and `use warnings`), which will allow you to skip the `or die $!` parts of the code.

Comment: Assuming you update the code with Borodin's response, if you still get the 'no such file or directory' error, then: check the path and make sure it is correct. If that doesn't work, then try escaping the path characters, e.g. you may have to provide \ rather than /, but I think Windows can handle it.

Comment: My bad! The global variable used to receive arguments was different from the one used in the open command. Usage of use strict and warnings helped identify the issue. I just learnt my first lesson in perl.

Answer (score -1):

code:

```
$file_name = $ARGV[1];

open (OUTPUT "> $file_name") or error("unable to create or open $file_name");

print OUTPUT "hello world";

close(OUTPUT);
```

command to execute:

```
perl perl_file.pl data.txt
```

it will work try

Comment: don't use 2-arg open... and what is the `error`-function you're calling?

Comment: error function is used for the purpose that if the file name is missed say ARGV is missed then it will print error message that what ever there in the (" "); even can use die also instead of error